# How to insert data into db with where clause using laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

**I am using this statement to insert the data.**

```
if(\App\tempLogin::insert(['otp'=>$otp])->where('mobile','=',$mobile))
  return 1;
```

but i got a error "Field 'username' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `tempLogin` (`otp`) values (8673))"

Comment: Insert with where does not make sense. Did you mean update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `update()` method to update information in existing DB rows:

```
\App\tempLogin::where('mobile', $mobile)->update(['otp' => $otp]);
```

`insert()` creates new row(s).